# Why is syncing Monero using a regular rotating disk drive so slow on a VPS?

Tags: monerod, synchronization

I managed to find a decent deal on a large 200GB vps for $5, but the only issue is that its on a regular rotating disk and not an SSD. I tried syncing ./monerod and its so slow to sync even 2%. It took over 24 hours. It's a 2 core cpu with 1GB of ram. Why is it so slow and how can I improve its sync speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is it so slow

Spinning hard drives are terribly slow compared to solid-state drives. Spinning hard drives you are sharing with multiple other workloads (i.e. in a shared environment, i.e. a VPS), are slow. Machines with low RAM and limited CPU cores are slow.

> and how can I improve its sync speed?

Using a server with a SSD is the simplest way to improve your sync speed. Further improvements can be gained by having more RAM and more CPU cores.

Comment: what if i'm willing to wait for it to 100% synch on a HDD? I don't mind as its a cheap $3 vps with alot of space.

Comment: You could always sync and verify on something else (more powerful, faster disk), then copy over the `.bitmonero` folder over to your cheap VPS. Or as you say, just wait.